# Правильно ли сформулировано предложение с точки зрения грамматики?

Tags: грамотная-речь, фразеология, выбор-слов

**"Наш курс - это полностью комплексный подход к тренировкам, питанию и вашей мотивации"** - в этом предложении сомневаюсь во фразе "комплексный подход к мотивации", это звучит не совсем правильно, имеется ли здесь ошибка?

Comment: Ваш вопрос не понятен. Добавьте, пожалуйста, контекст: что это за курс и что включает в себя комплексный подход. Если "тренировки, питание и мотивацию", тогда с точки зрения грамматики есть ошибки.

Answer (score 2):

Вы спрашиваете, правильно ли сформулировано предложение с точки зрения грамматики. Ответ положительный. Но есть подозрение на речевую ошибку, а именно на нарушение лексической сочетаемости. Думаю, лучше сказать "комплексный подход к усилению/укреплению/развитию вашей мотивации".

Дополнение.

А ведь прав grizzly (см. комментарии): речь о том, что тренировки, питание и мотивация рассматриваются как комплекс. В таком случае, по-моему, формулировку нужно изменить, например так:

**Наш курс основан на комплексном подходе, охватывающем тренировки, питание и мотивацию (к похудению).**

Примечания
1. Мне кажется, необходимо указать, о какой мотивации идет речь.
2. "Курс — это подход" заменено на "курс основан на подходе" (см. ответ Alex_ander).
3. Слово "полностью" удалено (см. ответ Ксении).

Comment: Думаю, что упомянутый комплексный подход (например, для курса оздоровления) включает в себя тренировки, питание и мотивацию (потому и комплексный).

Comment: @grizzly Тогда нужно писать "комплексный, включающий/охватывающий а,б и в".

Comment: Да. Я просто хотел обратить внимание всех, что не стоит отвечать на совершенно непонятный вопрос (а также плюсовать его).

Comment: @grizzly Я думаю, автор вопроса сам запутался, а мы ему помогли. Это поучительно для всех, поэтому плюс. По-моему, плюс — не только и не столько  поощрение автору, это знак для новых читателей, что на вопрос стоит обратить внимание.

Answer (score 1):

Здесь проблема не грамматическая. Неприятие может вызывать неясность логических связей использованного штампа "курс". **Курс** - это *направление*, поэтому можно "придерживаться курса", "следовать курсом", "выбирать курс" и т. п., а здесь произошло *отождествление* метода с курсом (*наш курс "является подходом"*), что звучит неестественно. Лучше вообще отказаться от этого слова из лексикона политиков и дипломатов (они зачастую используют такие слова исключительно для ухода от ответа на прямой вопрос) и сказать "**наш метод** (работы)".

Comment: *Курс - это направление* — ещё есть значения 3 и 4 [здесь](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81&all=x). Говорят, например, "курс оздоровления".

Comment: То есть здесь - что-то вроде коммерчески предлагаемого "курса лечения или занятий"? Тогда "наш курс предагает то-то", а не "является этим" - в таком контексте тоже неудачны связи слова.

Comment: Думаю, у автора курс обучения (учебная программа). Отождествлять курс с методом, формально говоря, неверно, но как троп — допустимо, по-моему.

Comment: Да. Меня смущает, что плохо поставленный вопрос (мне он не понятен, и я вижу, что участники понимают его по-разному) получает голоса хорошего вопроса и такие разношёрстные ответы.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант редактирования:

***Наш курс ― это комплексный подход как к тренировкам и питанию, так и к мотивации ваших занятий.***

1) Наречие ***полностью*** лишнее, оно плохо сочетается с относительным прилагательным ***комплексный***, которое обычно не требует определений, например:

Главной особенностью китайской медицины является **комплексный подход** к здоровью человека. [Клиника традиционной китайской медицины «ТАО» // «Огонек», 2014]

2) Не следует соединять союзом И такие разные предметы (может получиться  комический эффект), лучше разделить их на две группы с помощью составного союза.

Comment: Здесь мотивация - отглагольное от мотивировать?

Comment: С мотивацией вообще много тумана. Как правильно: мотивация человека или его активности? А может, мотивирование?

Comment: Вроде бы мотивация. Из словаря: МОТИВАЦИЯ, -и; ж. 1. =Мотивировка. М. чьих-л. действий, поступков. Неубедительная м. МОТИВИРОВАТЬ,  Привести - приводить мотивы, доводы, объясняющие, оправдывающие какое-л. действие, поступок, доказывающие необходимость какого-л. действия.